# alias on the left side of my avg result

Tags: sql, oracle, alias, average

How can I have an alias on the left side of my `avg` result ?

I have this avg sub-query

```
SELECT AVG(GRADE) AS GRADE
  FROM (
         SELECT AVG(NUMERIC_GRADE) AS GRADE
           FROM GRADE
          WHERE STUDENT_ID = 5 
            AND SECTION_ID = 17
          GROUP BY GRADE_TYPE_CODE
       ) myInnerTable;
```

and I get a result

```
     GRADE
----------
      82.3
```

I want to combine this with my avg result, do I have to use another column ?

```
SELECT INITCAP(GRADE_TYPE_CODE) AS "Average is:"
  FROM GRADE;
```

I want to have something like this

```
GRADE_TYPE_CODE         GRADE
----------------------- ------
Average Is:             82.3
```

Comment: aliases are always declared after (i.e. to the right of) the thing they are aliases for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    'Average Is:' AS GRADE_TYPE_CODE,
    AVG(GRADE) AS GRADE
FROM
(
    SELECT AVG(NUMERIC_GRADE) AS GRADE
FROM GRADE
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 5 AND SECTION_ID = 17
GROUP BY GRADE_TYPE_CODE
) myInnerTable;
```

Comment: so you do it on the left side instead of right, didn't expect it to be this simple...thank you